# ProxyPass(Apache2) with a DynDNS fails after getting a new IP-Address

Tags: apache, proxypass, dyndns

I'm getting a big headache with this issue and can't find a solution. I have the following setting.

An IP Camera connected to a Fritz.Box which is accessible via a dynamic DNS from selfhost.eu. And I have a Webserver with Apache2 with a ProxyPass to this xxx.selfhost.eu-URL. When someone access my webserver he will get a live update of the webcam because the ProxyPass works fine until the Fritz.Box gets a new IP-Address. Only when I restart the Apache2-Server it will work again, so my idea is that maybe Apache just caches the IP-Address and I've to stop that but I'm not sure.

Maybe someone has an idea. Thank you!

Here my ProxyPass-Setting

`ProxyPass "/tmpfs" "http://xxx.selfhost.eu:59677/tmpfs"`

And here some related Log-Error from apache

`2017-05-07 16:04:43    Error (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 79.210.185.5:59677 (xxx.selfhost.eu) failed Apache-Fehler
2017-05-07 16:04:43 Error AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (xxx.selfhost.eu) for 0s Apache-Fehler
2017-05-07 16:04:43 Error 79.204.237.78 AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: xxx.selfhost.eu, referer: https://xxx.yyy.de/ Apache-Fehler
2017-05-07 16:04:43 Error (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 79.210.185.5:59677 (xxx.selfhost.eu) failed Apache-Fehler
2017-05-07 16:04:43 Error 80.143.179.219 AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: xxx.selfhost.eu, referer: https://xxx.yyy.de/ Apache-Fehler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `disablereuse=On` help?

```
ProxyPass "/tmpfs" "http://xxx.selfhost.eu:59677/tmpfs" disablereuse=On
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the configuration I needed.